# C++-classes with SWIG

Tags: c++, python, swig

I try to create a python interface (with swig) from C++-code. With the code below. When I remove the line:

```
aClass z = aClass(1);
```

from the .cpp-file i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testit.py", line 3, in <module>
    import testlib
  File "(...)/testlib.py", line 26, in <module>
_testlib = swig_import_helper()
 File "(...)/testlib.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_testlib', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: (...)/_testlib.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6aClassC1Ei
```

What am I doing wrong?

**testlib.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class aClass {
    public:
        aClass(int i) {
            iD = i;
        }
        void printiD() {
            cout << iD << endl;
        }
    private:
        int iD;
};

void doSomething(string s) {
    cout << "testlib: I did something with:" << s << endl;
}

void outprintiD(aClass ff) {
    ff.printiD();
}
string returnSomething(string s) {
    return s;
}
//Don't know why, but without the next line it doesn't work. :(
aClass z = aClass(1);
```

**testlib.i**

```
%module testlib
%include "std_string.i"
using namespace std;
%{
    class aClass {
public:
    aClass(int i);
    void printiD();
private:
    int iD;
};
void outprintiD(aClass ff);
void doSomething(std::string s);
std::string returnSomething(std::string s);
%}
class aClass {
public:
    aClass(int i) ;
    void printiD();
private:
    int iD;
};
void outprintiD(aClass ff);
void doSomething(std::string s);
std::string returnSomething(std::string s);
```

**testit.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import testlib

testlib.doSomething("doS");
var = testlib.returnSomething("rSo");
print var

aClassInstance = testlib.aClass(42)
testlib.outprintiD(aClassInstance)

print "done..."
```

**execution script**

```
swig -c++ -python $1.i
g++ -c -fPIC $1.cpp $1_wrap.cxx -I/usr/include/python2.7
g++ -shared $1.o $1_wrap.o -o _$1.so
```

Comment: A guess: the linker is optimizing things away, because no other code is referencing it. try using gccs used attribute for the class

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I also thought so, but why would it work that way by default?..

Comment: @PlasmaHH Can you give an example how to use this?

Comment: @vines: Hysterical raisins? I was having massive problems with ar archives and statics that register stuff at creation. historically linkers seemed to leave out .o files where nothing was used from. Maybe these things slipped in. Linkers were never designed to support C++ (thus we have mangling).

Answer (score 0):

```
vines@Aspire-5755G:~$ c++filt _ZN6aClassC1Ei
aClass::aClass(int)
```

It's a linker error. Try:

```
g++ -shared $1_wrap.o $1.o -o _$1.so
```

i.e. swap the object files. It's because the order they are given matters, and it's reasonable to suppose that `$1_wrap.o` wants to pull some methods from `$1.o`.